# Borland C++: Ambiguity with std (error E2015)

Tags: c++, c++builder, ambiguity

I've been developing a DLL in Visual Studio 2005. At the moment it compiles and does what it's supposed to.

However, I wanted to compile it using Borland C++ 2006 because I've heard that is better and makes faster code. When I try to do it I get error messages like this one:

> E2015 Ambiguity between **strcmp**(const char *,const char *) and
>   std::**strcmp**(const char *,const char *)

I've changed every instance of strcmp to std::strcmp to solve the ambiguity problem and it works but I wonder if there is a smarter way to make this.

Thank you :-)

Comment: I am just curious as to where you heard that Borland was better? Was it an actual evaluations of the two? Or just word of mouth. I would expect MS and Borland to be fairly equal in this area, but...

Comment: It was "word of mouth" actually. But I've heard this from teachers and other studentds friends of mine. That's why I thought Borland C++ could be a better option.

Unfortunately, I can compile the source but I have problems when I execute it.

Comment: I don't know which one is better. At the moment I prefer Visual Studios's Enviroment. It's easer for me.

Comment: Didn't Borland only *just* get into the C++ compiler market again after something like an 8 year hiatus? If that is the case, I'd be skeptical of claims that they're "better". However, it's always good to test your code on multiple compilers. Can catch a lot of subtle errors that way.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have

```
#include <cstring>
```

and

```
#include <string.h>
```

and a

```
using namespace std;
```

in your code somewhere.  cstring declares std::strcmp, and string.h declares strcmp.  That is causing the ambiguity.  If you could avoid doing all 3 of these things, that would probably take care of your problem.